# Dúvida interpretação função

Tags: java

Tenho um HashMap utilizadores:

```
private Map<String, ObjectOutputStream> utilizadores = new HashMap<String, ObjectOutputStream>();
```

Alguém me sabe dizer o que está função faz ao certo? Aqui em nenhuma circunstancia é alterado o Hashmap pois não?

```
private synchronized void enviar_para_um(Mensagem mensagem){
        for(Map.Entry<String, ObjectOutputStream> mapa : utilizadores.entrySet()){
            if(mapa.getKey().equals(mensagem.getNomeClienteReceptorMensagem())) {       

                try {
                    mapa.getValue().writeObject(mensagem);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Transformando meus comentários em uma resposta.

O código em questão é umas espécie de *[Dispatcher Pattern](http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/MessageDispatcher.html)*. A ideia é enviar a mensagem escrevendo-a no `ObjectOutputStream` de determinado cliente (conforme o valor de `mensagem.getNomeClienteReceptorMensagem()`).

Para melhorar a performance eu reescreveria esse método da seguinte forma:

```
private synchronized void enviaParaIm(Mensagem mensagem){
    ObjectOutputStream oos = utilizadores.get(mensagem.getNomeClienteReceptorMensagem());
    if (oos != null) {
        try {
            oos.writeObject(mensagem);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Veja que dessa maneira o código fica mais limpo. Além disso há uma melhora de performance. O método inicial iterava todos os valores do mapa (tempo linear **O(n)**), enquanto o segundo faz um *lookup* direto, o que, para um `HashMap` roda em tempo constante amortizado (**O(1)**).

Answer (score 5):

O for abaixo vai percorrer todo o HashMap utilizadores. Para percorrer ele chama o método `entrySet()` que retorna um `Set<Map.Entry<K,V>>`.

```
for(Map.Entry<String, ObjectOutputStream> mapa : utilizadores.entrySet())
```

O if abaixo verifica se a chave do item do HashMap é igual a `mensagem.getNomeClienteReceptorMensagem()`.

```
if(mapa.getKey().equals(mensagem.getNomeClienteReceptorMensagem())) {
```

Em caso afirmativo, então o `value` do mapa é acessado, chamando o método `writeObject` e passando a `mensagem` como parametro.

```
mapa.getValue().writeObject(mensagem);
```

Entendo, portanto, que esse método faz o proposto, ou seja, envia a mensagem para um usuário apenas. O usuário em que o atributo `nomeClienteReceptorMensagem` da `mensagem` passada como parametro corresponda com uma das chaves do HashMap `utilizadores`.

Comment: So não entendi o motivo do desenvolvedor iterar o `HashMap` ao invés de fazer algo como `ObjectOutputStream oos = utilizadores.get(mensagem.getNomeClienteReceptorMensagem()); if (oos != null) { oos.writeObject(mensagem) }`. Parece que esse laço é desnecessário.

Comment: basicamente vai dar ao mesmo!

Comment: Bem observado @AnthonyAccioly. O loop é desnecessário nesse caso. O acesso por ser O(1), mas nesse caso está O(n). De qualquer maneira, tenho acompanhado o java, inclusvei já até falei com ele no chat. Ele está no processo de aprendizagem e parece que esse é um projeto de fim de curso.

Comment: @java, realmente o efeito é o mesmo, entretanto, o trecho de código proposto pelo AnthonyAccioly elimina a necessidade do loop. Se houvessem muitos usuários, então o loop seria muito mais lento do que o trecho de código proposto por ele. Note que um hashmap é uma estrutura de dados construída para que você possa acessar os dados em tempo O(1).

Comment: @cantoni a maneira que o anthony disse é mais perceptível! porem é tudo uma questão de rapidez no processamento de dados.

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly, vale uma resposta. Seu comentário enriquece a discussão.

Comment: Exato @java. Nesse caso, é mais uma questão de desempenho somada a uma clareza de código. Esse tipo de discussão é o que enriquece o SOpt. Portanto, tudo é válido quando o objetivo é aprender. :-)

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly meta aqui a sua resposta

Comment: @cantoni ajude me na outra questão que meti pff

Comment: Feito. E uma longa frase para o comentário passar.