# Interpretação função

Tags: java

Como fica esta função sem o ciclo for? usando o ObjectOutputStream?

```
private synchronized void adicionarListaContactosOnline(){
        Set<String> listaContactosOnline = new HashSet<String>();

        for(Map.Entry<String, ObjectOutputStream> mapa : utilizadores.entrySet()){
            listaContactosOnline.add(mapa.getKey());
        }

        Mensagem mensagem = new Mensagem();
        mensagem.setAccao(Accao.CONTACTOS_ONLINE);
        mensagem.setContactosOnline(listaContactosOnline);                                  

        for(Map.Entry<String, ObjectOutputStream> mapa : utilizadores.entrySet()){
            mensagem.setNomeClienteEnviaMensagem(mapa.getKey());
            try {
                System.out.println("Contacto Online: " + mapa.getKey());                
                mapa.getValue().writeObject(mensagem);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @cantoni como fica esta função com o outro método da pergunta anterior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Diferentemente dessa [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/103640/3084), nesse caso não há como retirar o laço for, pois você precisa iterar sobre todos utilizadores para criar um objeto `mensagem` para cada um.

O máximo que dá pra fazer é evitar dois laços sobre o mesmo HashMap, veja abaixo uma versão modificada:

```
private synchronized void adicionarListaContactosOnline(){
        Set<String> listaContactosOnline = new HashSet<String>();

        for(Map.Entry<String, ObjectOutputStream> mapa : utilizadores.entrySet()){
            listaContactosOnline.add(mapa.getKey());

            Mensagem mensagem = new Mensagem();
            mensagem.setAccao(Accao.CONTACTOS_ONLINE);
            mensagem.setContactosOnline(listaContactosOnline);                                  
            mensagem.setNomeClienteEnviaMensagem(mapa.getKey());

            try {
                System.out.println("Contacto Online: " + mapa.getKey());                
                mapa.getValue().writeObject(mensagem);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```